# Editing Room chatroom for Blog users

Tags: discussion, chat, blog

I've created a chatroom for editors/contributors to the UX blog:

## [The Editing Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3543/the-editing-room)

Hop in and say hello if you plan to be part of the blog or just start brainstorming ideas.